# AVCaptureSession working fine on iPad but not on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, avcapturesession

I am trying to make a video recording app using `AVCaptureSession`. 
I have a UIButton which gives the preview layer and sets up the session as follows:

```
-(void) video:(UIButton*)sender
{
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;

    captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    [captureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = cameraView.bounds;

    [cameraView.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
    AVCaptureDevice *frontCamera;
    AVCaptureDevice *backCamera;

    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices)
    {
        if ([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo])
        {
            if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack)
                backCamera = device;
            else
                frontCamera = device;
        }
    }
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:frontCamera error:nil];
    [session addInput:input];

    movieOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc]init];
    if ([session canAddOutput:movieOutput]) {
        [session addOutput:movieOutput];
    }

    [session startRunning];
}
```

Then one more UIButton to just start recording:

```
-(void) record:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Recording");

    outputURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    outputURL = [outputURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myVideo.mov"];
    NSString *filePath = [outputURL path];

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
    NSLog(@"is url :: %d", [outputURL isFileURL]);
    NSLog(@"does file exists :: %d",[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]);

    [movieOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];    
}
```

Now, I have no idea why this code works on iPad just fine but crashes on iPhone throwing error:

```
'*** -[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:] - no active/enabled connections.'
```

I looked around for solutions for this particular error but if something wrong with my code then why it works on iPad?

Note:

- My app is universal.
- On iPhones, it loads fine upto preview layer but crashes as soon as I start recording.
- I checked on more than one iPhone, same result.
- I did implement `captureOutput: didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL: fromConnections: error:`

**UPDATE**:
After so much of trial and error, I found out that if I add only audio as a input then the app works great on iPhones.

```
AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput * audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:nil];
    [session addInput:audioInput];
```

So problem should be in the way I add camera as input, although I didn't find any. And it works for iPads.

Comment: Try to change **videGravity** type.

Comment: @NilsHolgerson : No effect.. Anyways its a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer property.. Preview layer is working fine.. Problem comes when recording is started..

Comment: Do you need to request permission to use the camera, and you have previously allowed it on the iPad and forgotten? If you go to the settings app and then scroll down to you app do you see a camera permission option there on the iPad?

Comment: @GaryRiches : Yes I am allowed to use camera.I am getting preview layer fine, so camera is working with app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling for 2 days, I found the problem to be `sessionPreset` property which was `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`. And I solved it by just removing it so that it will use its default value.

Answer (score 0):

try below code may be help you.

```
-(void) record:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Recording");
            [[[self movieOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setVideoOrientation:(AVCaptureVideoOrientation)[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation];

    NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"movie" stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mov"]];

    NSLog(@"does file exists :: %d",[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]);

    [[self movieOutput] startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] recordingDelegate:self];
}
```

**OR** 
See below link

[AVCAM Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: It contains only NSLog for some checks, thats it.. And anyways app crashes before it reaches there.. Although everything goes smooth on iPad..

Comment: Do you try to debug it, Where exactly  it was crash ?

Comment: [movieOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];  error:: '*** -[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:] - no active/enabled connections.'

Comment: see my audited answer ant try it.

Comment: You have to set connectionWithMediaType so try my edited code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69123/discussion-between-blancos-and-dipen-chudasama).